# Implementing summation of a sequence in "vectorized" form instead of using loops, in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sum, vectorization

When I am implementing a summation of a series, for example:

[image: squared error cost function]

I use loops, as shown bellow:

```
H=f(x);
C0=0;
for i=1:p
    C0=C0+((y(i) - H(i))^2);    %//H and Y are vectors of the same size. The function f(x) makes sure of this
end

C1=0;
for j=1:m
    C1=C1+(L(j)*(w(j).^2));
end

C=C0+C1
```

In a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441457/neural-network-cost-function-in-matlab) I asked about a different summation series, and someone mentioned getting rid of the loops altogether and using matrix operations. They then provided me with a "vectorized" version. The code they provided me with worked perfectly, but I do not know how they went about deriving it from the summation series equation I provided.

So in general, how do you go about implementing a summation series in MATLAB without loops?

What are some general rules I can learn, so in future I can implement any summation series in vectorized form?

Thanks!

Comment: The `H=f(x)` seems very strange. Either it should be `H=f(i)` or you could palace it outside the loop.

Comment: Yes it should be placed outside the loop, i'll change that now.

Comment: Okay, then the first loop can be solved the same way. Everything you need to know is that subtraction is always element-wise (`-`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll skip the first loop, because I'm not sure how it's intended to work (->comment) and explain vectorisation for the second loop:

```
C1=0;
for j=1:m
    C1=C1+(L(j)*(w(j).^2));
end
```

What does the code do?

1. squaring each element of w
2. multiplying the result with the corresponding element in L
3. get the sum of the result.

To find the right operations, you have to know that there are matrix operations (`*`,`^`...) and element-wise operations (`.*`,`.^`...). If you don't know a used operation, type in `doc *`.

First step: Squaring element-wise can be done using `.^`

```
w.^2
```

now multiply with the corresponding elements in L

```
L.*(w.^2)
```

and get the sum of the resulting vector:

```
C1=sum(L.*(w.^2))
```