# Implement Cost Function of Neural Network (Week #5 Coursera) using Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Based on the Coursera Course for Machine Learning, I'm trying to implement the cost function for a neural network in python. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441457/neural-network-cost-function-in-matlab) similar to this one -- with an accepted answer -- but the code in that answers is written in octave. Not to be lazy, I have tried to adapt the relevant concepts of the answer to my case, and as far as I can tell, I'm implementing the function correctly. The cost I output differs from the expected cost, however, so I'm doing something wrong.

Here's a small reproducible example:

The following link leads to an `.npz` file which can be loaded (as below) to obtain relevant data. Rename the file `"arrays.npz"` please, if you use it.

http://www.filedropper.com/arrays_1

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

with np.load("arrays.npz") as data:

    thrLayer = data['thrLayer'] # The final layer post activation; you 
    # can derive this final layer, if verification needed, using weights below

    thetaO = data['thetaO'] # The weight array between layers 1 and 2
    thetaT = data['thetaT'] # The weight array between layers 2 and 3

    Ynew = data['Ynew'] # The output array with a 1 in position i and 0s elsewhere

    #class i is the class that the data described by X[i,:] belongs to

    X = data['X'] #Raw data with 1s appended to the first column
    Y = data['Y'] #One dimensional column vector; entry i contains the class of entry i



import numpy as np

m = len(thrLayer)
k = thrLayer.shape[1]
cost = 0

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(k):
        cost += -Ynew[i,j]*np.log(thrLayer[i,j]) - (1 - Ynew[i,j])*np.log(1 - thrLayer[i,j])
print(cost)
cost /= m

'''
Regularized Cost Component
'''

regCost = 0

for i in range(len(thetaO)):
    for j in range(1,len(thetaO[0])):
        regCost += thetaO[i,j]**2

for i in range(len(thetaT)):
    for j in range(1,len(thetaT[0])):
        regCost += thetaT[i,j]**2

regCost *= lam/(2*m) 


print(cost)
print(regCost)
```

In actuality, `cost` should be 0.287629 and `cost + newCost` should be 0.383770.

This is the cost function posted in the question above, for reference:

---

[image]

Comment: What value of lambda are you using? Also, to make sure, what value are you getting for cost (I get ~10.441)?

Comment: Can you give us the your source for the expected cost?

Comment: I'm very confident that your implementation of the cost function is correct. I think the problem is with your computation of the activations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the **wrong class labels**. When computing the cost function, you need to use the **ground truth**, or the true class labels.

I'm not sure what your Ynew array, was, but it wasn't the training outputs. So, I changed your code to use Y for the class labels in the place of Ynew, and got the correct cost.

```
import numpy as np

with np.load("arrays.npz") as data:

    thrLayer = data['thrLayer'] # The final layer post activation; you
    # can derive this final layer, if verification needed, using weights below

    thetaO = data['thetaO'] # The weight array between layers 1 and 2
    thetaT = data['thetaT'] # The weight array between layers 2 and 3

    Ynew = data['Ynew'] # The output array with a 1 in position i and 0s elsewhere

    #class i is the class that the data described by X[i,:] belongs to

    X = data['X'] #Raw data with 1s appended to the first column
    Y = data['Y'] #One dimensional column vector; entry i contains the class of entry i


m = len(thrLayer)
k = thrLayer.shape[1]
cost = 0

Y_arr = np.zeros(Ynew.shape)
for i in xrange(m):
    Y_arr[i,int(Y[i,0])-1] = 1

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(k):
        cost += -Y_arr[i,j]*np.log(thrLayer[i,j]) - (1 - Y_arr[i,j])*np.log(1 - thrLayer[i,j])
cost /= m

'''
Regularized Cost Component
'''

regCost = 0

for i in range(len(thetaO)):
    for j in range(1,len(thetaO[0])):
        regCost += thetaO[i,j]**2

for i in range(len(thetaT)):
    for j in range(1,len(thetaT[0])):
        regCost += thetaT[i,j]**2
lam=1
regCost *= lam/(2.*m)


print(cost)
print(cost + regCost)
```

This outputs:

```
0.287629165161
0.383769859091
```

**Edit:** Fixed an integer division error with `regCost *= lam/(2*m)` that was zeroing out the regCost.

Comment: Yes, `Ynew` definitely differs from `Y_arr`, and I think your implementation of `Y_arr` is correct. The original `Y` array has 100 `10`s, 100 `1`s, 100 `2`s and so forth up to 100 `9`s. I mapped the `10`s to the index 0 based on this comment from chapter 4, which used the same dataset: "Note that the y argument to this function is a vector of labels from 1 to
10, where we have mapped the digit \0" to the label 10 (to avoid confusions
with indexing)." I am not sure that this means anything different than what I thought?

Comment: Then the only uncertainty is why `0.0` is the regularized cost in place of ~ 0.38-0.28

Comment: You had integer division with regCost *= lam/(2*m) and were multiplying by 0. I fixed it and got the right regCost.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this implementation

```
import scipy.io
mat=scipy.io.loadmat('ex4data1.mat')
X=mat['X']
y=mat['y']

theta=scipy.io.loadmat('ex4weights.mat')
theta1=theta['Theta1']
theta2=theta['Theta2']
theta=[theta1,theta2]



new=np.zeros((10,len(y)))
for i in range(len(y)):
    new[y[i]-1,i]=1

y=new

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def reg_cost(theta,X,y,lambda1):
    current=X
    for i in range(len(theta)):
        a= np.append(np.ones((len(current),1)),current,axis=1)
        z=np.matmul(a,theta[i].T)
        z=sigmoid(z)
        current=z
    htheta=current
    ans=np.sum(np.multiply(np.log(htheta),(y).T)) + 
np.sum(np.multiply(np.log(1-htheta),(1-y).T))
    ans=-ans/len(X)
    for i in range(len(theta)):
        new=theta[i][:,1:]
        newsum=np.sum(np.multiply(new,new))
        ans+=newsum*(lambda1)/(2*len(X))

    return ans

print(reg_cost(theta,X,y,1))
```

It outputs

```
0.3837698590909236
```