# Why is this the correct way to do a cost function for a neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, vectorization, octave, backpropagation

So after beating my head against the wall for a few hours, I looked online for a solution to my problem, and it worked great. I just want to know what caused the issue with the way I was originally going about it.

[image]

[image]

here are some more details. The input is a 20x20px image from the MNIST datset, and there are 5000 samples, so X, or A1 is 5000x400. There are 25 nodes in the single hidden layer. The output is a one hot vector of 0-9 digits. `y` (not Y, which is the one hot encoding of y) is a 5000x1 vector with the value of 1-10.

[image]

Here was my original code for the cost function:

```
Y = zeros(m, num_labels);
   for i = 1:m
   Y(i, y(i)) = 1; 
endfor
H = sigmoid(Theta2*[ones(1,m);sigmoid(Theta1*[ones(m, 1) X]'))
J = (1/m) * sum(sum((-Y*log(H]))' - (1-Y)*log(1-H]))')))
```

But then I found this:

```
A1 = [ones(m, 1) X];
Z2 = A1 * Theta1';
A2 = [ones(size(Z2, 1), 1) sigmoid(Z2)];
Z3 = A2*Theta2';
H = A3 = sigmoid(Z3);

J = (1/m)*sum(sum((-Y).*log(H) - (1-Y).*log(1-H), 2));
```

I see that this may be slightly cleaner, but what functionally causes my original code to get `304.88` and the other to get ~ `0.25`? Is it the element wise multiplication?

FYI, this is the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441457/neural-network-cost-function-in-matlab/45364247#45364247) if you need the formal equation written out.

Thanks for any help I can get! I really want to understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? So that we can see the two codes actually in action?

Comment: @tryman Do those two screen grabs help clear it up? The whole problem is just writing a cost function for a neural network in Octave

Comment: @tryman I added a lot more details. Hopefully that will clear everything up

Comment: With a quick look, in `J = (1/m) * sum(sum((-Y*log(H]))' - (1-Y)*log(1-H]))')))` there is definetely something going on with the parenthesis, but probably on how you pasted it here, not with the original code as this would throw an error when you run it. If I understand correctly and Y, H are matrices, then in your 1st version `Y*log(H)` is matrix multiplication while in the 2nd version `Y.*log(H)` is an entrywise multiplication (not matrix-multiplication, just c(i,j)=a(i,j)*b(i,j) ).

Comment: @tryman thanks! What I’m really trying to figure out is how I was supposed to know to do an element wise multiply instead of matrix wise, just from those equations and figures above. Since In that equation, y and log don’t have some kind of * does that technically mean it’s element wise? Or is there something else here I’m not getting

Comment: If you mean they don't have `*` in the printscreen you provided, these are values. In octave you put the values inside a matrix so that you can work on all of them at once. However you want to do the operations corresponding each value of the one matrix to the other, not actually multiply the matrices. As of `.*`, it is just semantics of the Octave & Matlab language that means perform it entry by entry and not as matrix. (Transferred most of the comments as an answer. At first I was not sure at what point exactly was your block, that's why I wrote it as comment). Note there may be (1/2)

Comment: other errors as well. This was not with a comprehensive look. (2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer from the comments:
With a quick look, in `J = (1/m) * sum(sum((-Y*log(H]))' - (1-Y)*log(1-H]))')))` there is definetely something going on with the parenthesis, but probably on how you pasted it here, not with the original code as this would throw an error when you run it. If I understand correctly and Y, H are matrices, then in your 1st version `Y*log(H)` is matrix multiplication while in the 2nd version `Y.*log(H)` is an entrywise multiplication (not matrix-multiplication, just `c(i,j)=a(i,j)*b(i,j)` ).

Update 1:
In regards to your question in the comment.
From the first screenshot, you represent each value yk(i) in the entry `Y(i,k)` of the Y matrix and each value h(x^(i))k as `H(i,k)`. So basically, for each i,k you want to compute `Y(i,k) log(H(i,k)) + (1-Y(i,k)) log(1-H(i,k))`. You can do it for all the values together and store the result in matrix C. Then `C = Y.*log(H) + (1-Y).*log(1-H)` and each C(i,k) has the above mentioned value. This is an operation `.*` because you want to do the operation for each element (i,k) of each matrix (in contrast to [multiplying the matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) which is totally different). Afterwards, to get the sum of all the values inside the 2D dimensional matrix C, you use the octave function `sum` twice: `sum(sum(C))` to sum both columnwise and row-wise (or as @ Irreducible suggested, just `sum(C(:))`).

Note there may be other errors as well.

Comment: To sum over all entries of a matrix `C` just write: `sum(C(:))`

Comment: @Irreducible That too! Incorporated your suggestion.